# i want to create table dynamically in a specific position of the html page

Tags: javascript, html

**i am trying to create the table using js in a specific location of the page**
**i m getting the output but also getting an error undefind before the result**
**before the table creation an error is shown undefine any solution for this**

```
<script>
function tab()
{   
   var x=4;
function tabb(){
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.id="a-table";
for (var i = 1; i < x; i++){
var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
tr.id="myrow";
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
var td2 = document.createElement('td');


tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);

table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML=tabb();
var cells = document.getElementById("a-table").getElementsByTagName("td");
        var i=0;
        for(i = 0; i < x+1; i++){
        var cell = cells[i];
        cell.innerHTML = "<img class=img1 src=faculty/comm/"+i+".jpg>";

        }


 }
 </script>
<style>
td {
border: solid 1px #000;
border-style: none solid solid none;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:8px;
}
</style>
<body>
<input type=button onclick="tab()" value="create">
<div id="tab"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: [https://prnt.sc/fqg6ma](https://prnt.sc/fqg6ma) "screenshot of Error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this will remove the `undefined` from the page, I strongly recommend you to consider more clean, optimized `tab` function.

```js
function tab()
{
var x=4;
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.id="a-table";
for (var i = 0; i < x; i++){
var tr = document.createElement('tr');   
tr.id="myrow";
var td1 = document.createElement('td');
var td2 = document.createElement('td');


tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2);

table.appendChild(tr);
}
document.getElementById("tab").appendChild(table);

var cells = document.getElementById("a-table").getElementsByTagName("td");
        var i=0;
        for(i = 0; i < x+1; i++){
        var cell = cells[i];
        cell.innerHTML = "<img class=img1 src=faculty/comm/"+i+".jpg>";

        }


 }
```

```css
td {
border: solid 1px #000;
border-style: none solid solid none;
padding: 10px;
border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<input type=button onclick="tab()" value="create">
<div id="tab"></div>
```